# Unhandled Exception in ASP.Net Core Web API on Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 WebAPI with a single node.  (This is essentially a proxy endpoint to not have to deal with a nightmarish Whitelist at the ultimate end of this chain.)  The clients, which I also control, all send programmatically identical requests to the proxy.  Sometimes, or often, the Kestral server reports the following errors in the Linux server's syslog.

```
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content.
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason)
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.ReadAsyncInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMeta
data metadata, Object value)
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boo
lean isCompleted)
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isComple
ted)
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Oct  2 19:06:52 CCBD-Status-API-East CCBD-Status-API[979]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

the request is very small

```
{'Url': '<URL data>', 'Status': 0}
```

API Controller code:

```
public IActionResult GetStreamStatus([FromBody] StreamInfo input)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest();
        NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(_config.Value.User, _config.Value.Pass);
        var cred = new CredentialCache();
        cred.Add(new Uri(input.Url), "Digest", netCred);
        _logger.LogInformation($"Attempting to get status from: {input.Url}");
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler {Credentials = cred, PreAuthenticate = true});
        var resp = httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(input.Url));
        _logger.LogInformation($"{input.Url} returned: {resp.Result.StatusCode}");
        input.Status = (int) resp.Result.StatusCode;

        return Ok(input);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e.ToString());
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs Configure Method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
    {
        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        var exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error;

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {error = exception.Message});
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }));

    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

EDIT:  Adding Client Code

```
def check_stream(tc, app, feed, server):
    try:
        logger.info("Check Stream: {}".format(server))
        stream_url = ""
        if server == 'pri':
            stream_url = <Building URL>
        elif server == 'bak':
            stream_url = <Building URL>

        json_input = {"Url": stream_url, "Status": 0}
        logger.info(json_input)
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

        resp = requests.post(<Proxy URL>, data=json.dumps(json_input),
                             headers=headers)
        
        logger.info(resp.headers)
        logger.info("Response Text: {}".format(resp.text))
        results = json.loads(resp.text)
        code = results.get('status')

        return code
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Stream Check exception: {} {}".format(type(e).__name__, str(e.args)))
```

Comment: The stack trace says the http request ends sooner than expected - this strongly suggests the problem is either in how the client is sending requests, or at some stage between the client and the server. Do you have the client code?

Comment: @JasonHolloway Added Client code in edit.

Comment: There's nothing that jumps out as being wrong with that - at this point I'd try finding out what exactly is making it to the server, which is very doable (via googling), especially if the server is on linux. You should be able to use `tcpdump` to capture all incoming messages and then use something like Wireshark to read the dump afterwards. Basically I think something inbetween the client and the server is messing with the requests - sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: This thread shows the kind of thing you're facing, even if the details aren't exactly the same: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16807 I note at the end the suggestion to turn on trace-level logs on the server (see link towards bottom), maybe that will show something

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing, I just see that you get `resp` asynchronously and then use it as if it was already loaded, which may not be true. Maybe you should wait for the `*Async` requests to complete? And, on that note, are you sure the moment you get to process the data from the stream that the message is actually complete? On some frameworks (node.js) you get fragments of messages and have to recombine them before you can process the whole message. Not doing so causes a similar exception. just 2 things that came to my mind...

Comment: @pid So I modified those lines to get the Response before processing anything further.  No change.  It seems like it's the request coming into the API rather than the request the API is making out to the end node.  I've done several other ASP.Net APIs with no issues like this before, in relation to having to rebuild the request as you mentioned.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  I shifted the node to be async and it works without issue.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetStreamStatusAsync([FromBody] StreamInfo input)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest();
        NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(_config.Value.User, _config.Value.Pass);
        var cred = new CredentialCache();
        cred.Add(new Uri(input.Url), "Digest", netCred);
        _logger.LogInformation($"Attempting to get status from: {input.Url}");
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler {Credentials = cred, PreAuthenticate = true});
        var resp = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(input.Url));
        _logger.LogInformation($"{input.Url} returned: {resp.StatusCode}");
        input.Status = (int) resp.StatusCode;

        return Ok(input);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e.ToString());
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```